# Abrir una dirección web con Process.start

Tags: c#

Con este procedimiento puedo abrir mi pagina

```
Process.Start("http://www.dominio.es/pt/traductor.aspx");
```

Pero me gustaría abrir la página como una ventana con unas propiedades de tamaño, entonces, no se si utilizar esta función o si hay otra.

Gracias

Comment: Para que navegador?

Comment: Este procedimiento no abre tu pagina.. este procedimiento le dice a windows que use el programa por defecto que usa para abrir este tipo de cossas, que es un link a una pagina web.. ahora que entendimos eso, que es lo que queres hacer???

Comment: Que yo sepa no existe una solución genérica. Necesitas abrir el navegador con los parámetros necesarios. Puedes encontrar los de chrome [aquí](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: Si nos puedes comentar cual es el requerimiento completo, además de abrir el explorador, por ejemplo desde que aplicacion necesitas lanzar esto? el usuario final lo tendra que hacer? porque necesitas abrirlo? si nos comentas mas el escenario te podremos ayudar mejor

Comment: Al final he usado lo siguiente:
NavPrograma.AllowWebBrowserDrop = false;
NavPrograma.Url = new Uri("http://www.dominio.es/pt/traductorMaxi.aspx");
Era lo que mas se ajustaba a mis necesidades